# Is u in the subset of $R^3$ spanned by the columns of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

u = 
$\begin{pmatrix}
4\\-1\\4
\end{pmatrix}$

and

A =
$\begin{pmatrix}
2&5&-1\\0&1&-1\\1&2&0
\end{pmatrix}$

How can I determine if u is in the subset of $R^3$ spanned by the columns of A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to check, row reduce the augmented matrix
$$
(A|u) = \pmatrix{
2&5&1&\vdots&4\\0&1&-1&\vdots&-1\\1&2&0&\vdots&4
}
$$
If this system is consistent, then $u$ is in the span.  If the system is inconsistent, then $u$ is not in the span.

Answer (score 1):

Write $u$ as a linear combination of the columns of $A$

$$
u  = a\pmatrix{2\\5\\1}+b\pmatrix{5\\1\\2}+c\pmatrix{1\\-1\\0} = \pmatrix{4\\-1\\4}
$$

which gives you a linear system of 3 equations in 3 unknowns, try to solve it for $a,b,c$ if it admits a solution then $u$ is spanned by the columns of $A$